# Simplest way to pull a Microsoft DLL into a VS project?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package-restore

I need to download `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll v3.19.8.16603` into my .NET project. I would have thought this is a simple task, but I'm running into one problem after another, and I fear these are all noob problems. I have tried 3 different approaches:

**APPROACH #1**
*VS2019 - NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution*

[image]

Why "No packages found"? I know it exists.

**APPROACH #2**
*VS2019 - NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console*

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory -Version 3.19.8
```

Result:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.3.19.8' with respect to project '_JunkTest', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'
Install-Package : Package 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.19.8' is not found in the following primary source(s): 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 
21.2\Components\System\Components\Packages,C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'. Please verify all your online package sources are available (OR) 
package id, version are specified correctly.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory -Vers ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

**APPROACH #3**
*VS2019 - Developer Command Prompt*

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory --version 3.19.8
```

Result:

```
  Determining projects to restore...
  Writing C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpF88E.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory' into project 'D:\Dev\Git\_JunkTest\_JunkTest.csproj'.
error: Error while adding package 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory' to project 'D:\Dev\Git\_JunkTest\_JunkTest.csproj'. The project does not support adding package references through the add package command.
```

In actuality, I don't even need a reference to that DLL in this project. I just need the DLL along with any of its dependencies so I can copy them into some other projects I have, but I don't want to muddy those by nugetting directly in. Or at least I want to figure it out in this junk project first. I'm really just looking for the easiest way to download the DLL(s).

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources

Comment: Hans, I can't see how to set nuget.org as my package source. It's not an available option that I can see.

Comment: Figured it out: source must be added, and must be this: `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/`. Thank you Hans.

Comment: that url is deprecated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/overview-nuget-org#api-endpoint-for-nugetorg  You should use `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`